# Excel time after 00:00:00 in formula display as 01.01.1900 00:00:01

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am preparing a file that, based on the time during the day, adds breaks occurring at specific times based on the "if" function. If there is a gap in the interval, it is added to the time. Until 23:59:59 it works ok, after midnight it does not find breaks because it sees the time as, for example, 01/01/1900 00:03:16. I can't use copy as a value to delete 01/01/1900 manually. Maybe someone has an idea?

I'm using that formula - if in specify period there is break → show break time, if not display 00:00:00 - i think formula is not a problem, problem might be time format in AO column.
I tried also change time format (hh:mm:ss) , change as text etc but still fail.

```
=IF(AND(AO16>$BI$11,AO16<$BI$12),$BK$11,
IF(AND(AO16>$BI$13,AO16<$BI$14),$BK$13,
IF(AND(AO16>$ BI$15,AO16<$BI$16),$BK$15,
IF(AND(AO16>$BI$17,AO16<$BI$18),$BK$17,
IF(AND(AO16>$BI$19,AO16<$BI$20) );$BK$19;
IF(AND(AO16>$BL$11;AO16<$BL$12);$BN$11;
IF(AND(AO16>$BL$13;AO16<$BL$14);$BN$13;
IF( AND(AO16>$BL$15,AO16<$BL$16),$BN$15,
IF(AND(AO16>$BL$17,AO16<$BL$18),$BN$17,
IF(AND(AO16>$BL$19; AO16<$BL$20);$BN$19;
"00:00:00"))))))))))
```

Comment: Don't really understand how is that formula working for you, in your formula sometimes you have comma as a separator and sometimes as semicolon. Should be getting a error message firstoff. Also found one parenthesis extra for the fifth nested `IF()`. are all these typos?

Answer (score 0):

Everything is ok, it's just the way your data is displayed which is wrong.

I have created a simple Excel file, containing two times the same formula (`=TIME(0,0,1)`).

The first time, I've formatted the cell as `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss` and it looks as weird as yours: `00/01/1900 00:00:01`.
The second time, I've formatted the cell as `hh:mm:ss` and the cell simply shows `00:00:01`.

Right-click on the cell, this is what you get:
[image]

Choose (or enter) whatever custom format you wish:

[image]

Comment: Hi, i did that before (change format cells to hh:mm:ss) ,display looks ok,  anyway if you will copy and paste  as value any hour after midnight in formula window you will see still : 01.01.1900 & hour

Comment: Don't "Paste", but "Paste Values". This keeps the formatting.